# switch between tabs in ie

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, add-in

I am going to write a code in c# or Delphi (maybe Add-ins)  that automatically (for example every 5 seconds) switch between tabs in IE (Internet explorer). 
Please help me.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? What have you done so far? Does it have to be IE? Would you rather use off-the-shelf software and write a script to switch tabs? 

Please see [iMacros](http://www.iopus.com/imacros/compare/all/) I think they would be a decent off-the-shelf software that would cut down on your development time.